# I want to enable pagination in my elasticsearch results by adding new page of results below the older one in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, pagination, elastic-stack

I am Building an UI (using ReactJs) for a search engine (using elasticsearch) and it returns 20 results per page.
When I click next button, it gives out next 20 results but old results are replaced by the new one. All I want is that the new results should be appended to the old results.

here is my code :

```
import React from 'react'
import SearchResults from './searchresults';
import elasticsearch from 'elasticsearch';

let client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
})


var size = 20;
var from_size = 0;
var search_query = '*'

class Searchbox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { results: [], notFound: true }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    this.prev = this.prev.bind(this);
    this.er = this.er.bind(this);
    this.esSearch = this.esSearch.bind(this);
} 

componentWillMount() {
    search_query = '*';
    this.esSearch(search_query, from_size);
}

handleChange ( event ) {
    search_query = event.target.value + '*';
    from_size = 0;
    this.esSearch(search_query, from_size);
}

next() {
    from_size += size;
    if(from_size<=size) {
    console.log(from_size);
    console.log(search_query);
    this.esSearch(search_query, from_size);
}
    else {
        this.er();
        from_size -= size;
    }
}

er() {
    alert("NO MORE PAGES");
}

esSearch( sq, from ) {
    var search_query = sq;

    client.search({
        index: 'photos',
        type: 'photo',
        q: search_query,
        size: size,
        from: from
    }).then(function ( body ) {
        if(body.hits.max_score===null) {
            this.setState({notFound: true})
        }
        else {
            this.setState({notFound: false})
        }
        this.setState({ results: body.hits.hits })
    }.bind(this), function ( error ) {
        console.trace( error.message );

    });
}

renderNotFound() {
return <div className="notFound">Not found. Try a different search.</div>;
}

renderPosts() {

    return(
        <div className="results">
                    <SearchResults key={this.from_size} results={ this.state.results } />
                    <button id="prev" type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.prev} >Prev</button>
                </div>
    )

}

render() {

    const { notFound } = this.state;

    return (
        <div>
            <input id="search" className="form-control form" type="text" placeholder="Start Searching" name="search" onChange={ this.handleChange }></input>
                <div>
                    {notFound ? this.renderNotFound() : this.renderPosts()}
                </div>
        </div>
    )
}

}

export default Searchbox;
```

This app by default, shows all the results.

Comment: In your esSearch function, you are adding results to your state, effectively overwriting whats already in it. You should find a way to append the results.

Comment: That's what my question is @VedranMaricevic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your esFunction, you could try something like this:

```
let oldState = this.state.results.slice();
body.hits.hits.forEach(function (searchResult) {
    oldState.push(searchResult)    
});

this.setState({
    results: oldState
});
```

There is a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131109/update-state-or-parent-component-in-react) that talks about this topic.
More [details](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) at Facebook React page.

Comment: no, @VedranMaricevic. It didn't solve my problem. As Elasticsearch's main object starts at body.hits.hits that is transferred to results. using this function is breaking properties inside of the results that are helping to show the results.

Comment: Please update your question with sample of current results, and with data that comes from ES, so we can see what is breaking the results.

Comment: The Code I wrote is working fine. the next() increases the search index by 20 so that 20 new resukts can be shown. All I want is that The results shown on first query should remain. and by clicking next button, New results are shown below. Like this one : [here](http://yildizberkay.com/redux-example/)

Comment: You already have an array of ES results in your state. You send a query for a new set. That set comes in, and has same structure. You add the new data to the old data, so the page updates. Do I have this correct?

Comment: Thats why I asked you to show existing sample of the data and new set of data that comes from ES. hits.hits should contain an array of objects from your search result.

Comment: [Sample Data](http://rohitmotwani.com/data.json) Coming from ES, when size=10 and from=0

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please see if that fixes the problem. Generally, that should work for you, however that code is not tested, but should push you in good direction.

Comment: Still Not Workig :( Returning : **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '_source' of undefined**

Comment: I did update of my answer several times. Have you used the last update?

Comment: Yep, I did. Still it shoes the same thing

Comment: Great, Thanks. That Worked ! I want to understand the logic of code :) Thanks a lot. It Worked